# Using HTML Templates at server side

Tags: html, json, string, scala, playframework

I am working on play framework with SCALA as backend.
Json data is given to the front end from the controller.

I want to add HTML as value of some fields of json.
This HTML will be kept as a template and data will be added in this template at run time.

I think i should put unique names in the HTML template and then these names will be replaced by the data which i want to add at run time. Ultimately, this HTML will be added in the json response.

Is my approach right? If not, what is the best approach to add data in an HTML template,add this template in json response and send this combined response to the front-end for further use?

Is it a good practice to use string replacement to add data in an HTML template?

Comment: What is the use-case for embedding HTML in JSON? If you want to go a bit beyond simple string-replacement, you may want to look at a template engine such as FreeMarker.

Comment: So are you using Play templates as you front-end or you just use Play as a back-end and something else as a UI?

Comment: @rethab the front-end of my application uses this json to visualize it in a table. In some columns of the table, i want to show cutomized HTML. That is why i am embedding it.Would you suggest me to use freemakrer in playframework with scala as backend?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar , mine is the second case. I am using ajax calls to bring json data and show in a table with HTML embedded in it. I do not want to do the processing at front-end, therefore i want to send embedded HTML from the backend. I want to keep the HTML template in separate files so that it can be easily modified, without changing the backend code.

Comment: As long as you can do it with play templates, you should probably stick with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as long as you use Play, you can put your HTML templates into app/views package. Let's say you call your template mytemplate.scala.html
You can parameterize this view as any Play view.
In the place in your code where you generate your JSON response you can then call mytemplate(parameters) to get html generated, Play will do all the work here for you. Then using play.api.libs.json.JSON object's methods and related facilities you can convert this html to JSON.
So in your controller's code you will have something like Ok(JSON.toJson(mytemplate(parameters)))

This is of course a sketch, so you will need to elaborate and try.

Comment: Ok.
Is this the standard way?
As i would have to call the template for as many times as the number of documents i have, add these to a list and then send the same to front-end to be shown in a table.This may be in order of hundreds.

Comment: Such Play view is actually a function with parameters when it gets compiled. So no problems if you call it hundreds times.
Review also this part of Play documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson if you have not yet done this. It is more about serialization to JSON your model objects but still I think can be useful for you.